# extending existing line in QGIS by adding nodes

Tags: qgis, line

I am trying to extend an existing line by adding nodes to it.  Is this possible to do in QGIS without creating a whole new line?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add new nodes to the line by using the [Node Tool](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#node-tool), it will allow you to add a new node to the line by double-clicking it, then you can just adjust the node to extent your line as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the feature and use the 'Add part' tool.

[image]

Comment: -1 Add part adds a polygon part to a selected multipolygon.

Comment: My fault, only tested with line (not multi line) scratch layers where 'Add Part' is working.